# Java GPA Calc result Issues

Tags: java, eclipse, double, calculator

### GPA Calculator

I know there are similar threads out there but none that i have seen have come across the problem I am experiencing. I am receiving no errors yet my final answer is always 0 instead of an actual GPA value. Any help would be greatly appreciated! **Note**: I am new to Java this is my first official project after hours of reading about Java.

```
public static void main (String[]args){


    double total = 0,total2=0, total3=0, total4=0, total5=0, total6=0;
    double classes=0;
    double answer=0;
    String grade1,grade2,grade3,grade4,grade5,grade6;
    int p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6;



System.out.println("Welcome to the Gpa Calc");
System.out.println("Please enter a grade for every class you have.");
System.out.println("Shall we begin?");
System.out.println("How many classes do you have?");
    Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
    classes= c.nextInt();

    Scanner grade = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your Grade in your first period class?");
    grade1 = grade.nextLine();
    if(grade1 == "A" || grade1 =="a"){
         p1 = 4;
         total+=p1;
    }
    else if(grade1 == "B" || grade1 =="b"){
        p1= 3;
        total+= p1;
    }
    else if(grade1 == "C" || grade1 =="c"){
        p1= 2;
        total+= p1;
    }
    else if(grade1 == "D" || grade1 =="d"){
        p1= 1;
        total += p1;
    }
    else if(grade1 == "F" || grade1 =="f"){
        p1= 0;
        total += p1;
    }   

    System.out.println("What is your Grade in your second period class?");
    grade2 = grade.nextLine();

    if(grade2 == "A" || grade2 =="a"){
         p2 = 4;
         total2 += p2;
    }
    else if(grade2 == "B" || grade2 =="b"){
         p2 = 3;
         total2 += p2;
    }
    else if(grade2 == "C" || grade2 =="c"){
         p2 = 2;
         total2 += p2;
    }
    else if(grade2 == "D" || grade2 =="d"){
         p2 = 1;
         total2 += p2;
    }
    else if(grade2 == "F" || grade2 =="f"){
         p2 = 0;
         total2 += p2;
    }   

    System.out.println("What is your Grade in your third period class?");
    grade3 = grade.nextLine();

    if(grade3 == "A" || grade3 =="a"){
         p3 = 4;
         total3 += p3;
    }
    else if(grade3 == "B" || grade3 =="b"){
         p3 = 3;
         total3 += p3;
    }
    else if(grade3 == "C" || grade3 =="c"){
         p3 = 2;
         total3 += p3;
    }
    else if(grade3 == "D" || grade3 =="d"){
         p3 = 1;
         total3 += p3;
    }
    else if(grade3 == "F" || grade3 =="f"){
         p3 = 0;
         total3 += p3;
    }   

    System.out.println("What is your Grade in your fourth period class?");
    grade4 = grade.nextLine();

    if(grade4 == "A" || grade4 =="a"){
         p4 = 4;
         total4 += p4;
    }
    else if(grade4 == "B" || grade4 =="b"){
         p4 = 3;
         total4 += p4;
    }
    else if(grade4 == "C" || grade4 =="c"){
         p4 = 2;
         total4 += p4;
    }
    else if(grade4 == "D" || grade4 =="d"){
         p4 = 1;
         total4 += p4;
    }
    else if(grade4 == "F" || grade4 =="f"){
         p4 = 0;
         total4 += p4;
    }   

    System.out.println("What is your Grade in your fifth period class?");
    grade5 = grade.nextLine();

    if(grade5 == "A" || grade5 =="a"){
         p5 = 4;
         total5 += p5;
    }
    else if(grade5 == "B" || grade5 =="b"){
         p5 = 3;
         total5 += p5;
    }
    else if(grade5 == "C" || grade5 =="c"){
         p5 = 2;
         total5 += p5;
    }
    else if(grade5 == "D" || grade5 =="d"){
         p5 = 1;
         total5 += p5;
    }
    else if(grade5 == "F" || grade5 =="f"){
         p5 = 0;
         total5 += p5;
    }   
    System.out.println("What is your Grade in your sixth period class?");
    grade6 = grade.nextLine();

    if(grade6 == "A" || grade6 =="a"){
         p6 = 4;
         total6 += p6;
    }
    else if(grade6 == "B" || grade6 =="b"){
         p6 = 3;
         total6 += p6;
    }
    else if(grade6 == "C" || grade6 =="c"){
         p6 = 2;
         total6 += p6;
    }
    else if(grade6 == "D" || grade6 =="d"){
         p6 = 1;
         total6 += p6;
    }
    else if(grade6 == "F" || grade6 =="f"){
         p6 = 0;
         total6 += p6;
    }   


    answer = total + total2 + total3 + total4 + total5 + total6 ;
    double GPA = answer/classes;
    System.out.println("Your current unweighed GPA is " +GPA);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use grade1.isEquals("A") to compare the strings. grade1 == "A" compares the object identity, which will be false since they are different objects.  You might also consider doing away with the long 'if' chains and instead go with:

```
answer += grade1.toLowerCase().indexOf("fdcba"); // returns the zero based index 0-4 for f-a
```

it's a little more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a single character to comparison you can replace your comparison code with this:

```
  char grade1 = grade.nextLine().charAt(0);
       if(grade11 == 'A' || grade11 =='a'){
            // 
        }
```

NOTE:And also try to make your code modular. Create a method that accepts a grade param and return the gpa and get ride all the repeating codes

Comment: If you do this, "Awesome", "Bob", "Carl", "Dumbass" and "Failure" are now valid grades.

Answer (score 0):

So what is happening is that none of your conditionals are ever being met because you are using `==`. That would work fine when comparing ints but Strings are a little bit different. In basic terms `==` checks if the location of the data is the same.  You need to use `equals()` instead because it checks if the value of the data is the same. For example

```
if(grade1.equals("A") || grade1.equals("a")){
     p1 = 4;
     total+=p1;
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) has some excellent answers describing the difference between `==` and `equals`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who has commented so far! You have no idea how frustrating this was for me as i am new to Java! Its evident my issue was related to the usage of `==` instead of `equals` . I've furthered my knowledge on Java because of you all. Thanks! @LubedUpSlug @Randy Kamradt Sr. @ambes